# PATCH is not working django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am performing CRUD,all endpoints are working except update(patch).Getting

```
KeyError at /apponboarding/app/1/
'email'
```

if I am passing only the field which I want to update. Any help is highly appreciated.

**viewset**

```py
class AppOnboardingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AppOnboarding.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppOnboardingSerializer
    lookup_field='id'
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,IsMaintainer]
```

**serializer**

```py
class AppOnboardingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppOnboarding
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'product_name', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        app_onboard = AppOnboarding(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            product_name=self.validated_data['product_name']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        app_onboard.set_password(password)
        app_onboard.save()

    def save(self):
        app_onboard = AppOnboarding(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            product_name=self.validated_data['product_name']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        app_onboard.set_password(password)
        app_onboard.save()
```

Comment: by using the `ModelViewSet`, the method `perform_update` calls the `save` method on your Serializer - and you are overriding it's function by always creating a new `AppOnboarding` object and using both the password and the email fields from `validated_data`. That's what causing the error.

Comment: So what's the way out?

Answer (score 0):

Try override method partial_update

```
 class AppOnboardingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppOnboarding
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'product_name', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        app_onboard = AppOnboarding(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            product_name=self.validated_data['product_name']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        app_onboard.set_password(password)
        app_onboard.save()

    def save(self):
        app_onboard = AppOnboarding(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            product_name=self.validated_data['product_name']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        app_onboard.set_password(password)
        app_onboard.save()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```